# F# substitute expression in expression tree

Tags: f#, tree

Given an `expression tree` with the type:

```
type Fexpr =
    | Const of float
    | X
    | Add of Fexpr * Fexpr
    | Sub of Fexpr * Fexpr
    | Mul of Fexpr * Fexpr
    | Div of Fexpr * Fexpr
```

I want to make a function, which substitutes an expression in the tree with another expression. Example:

`substX: Fexpr -> Fexpre -> Fexpr`

Such that `substX e' e` returns the expression from `e` where each occurence of `X` has been replaced by `e'`:

```
let ex = (Mul,X, Add(Const 2.0, X))

substX (Div(X,X)) ex
```

Would return

`(Mul,Div(X,X), Add(Const 2.0, Div(X,X))`

I'm not entirely sure where to start on this one, so any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Look into [zippers](http://erichgess.github.io/blog/2015/08/17/f-number-zippers/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your function's input is a sum type (aka "discriminated union"), your function has to consist of instructions on what to do for every case of the sum. For this F# offers a facility called "pattern matching":

```
let substEx subst ex = match ex with
    ...
```

Now, let's go through the cases: if the input is `Const`, then the output should be the same `Const` - there is nothing to substitute in it. If the input is `X`, then the output should be whatever we're substituting - that's the whole point of the function. So far so good. Let's write it down:

```
let substEx subst ex = match ex with
   | Const c -> Const c
   | X -> subst
    ...
```

OK, now what do we do about `Add`? The result of substituting `X` in an `Add` expression would be also an `Add` expression, whose arguments are results of substituting `X` in the original `Add`'s arguments. But how do I substitute `X` in the arguments? If only there was a function to do that... Oh, wait a second! That's the very function we're currently writing! Let's write that down:

```
let rec substEx subst ex = match ex with
   | Const c -> Const c
   | X -> subst
   | Add r l -> Add (substEx subst r) (substEx subst l)
    ...
```

Notice the `rec` in the function declaration. It stands for "recursive" and is required, because our function is now calling itself.

Finally, let's do the same thing for `Sub`, `Mul`, and `Div`, and we're done:

```
let rec substEx subst ex = match ex with
   | Const c -> Const c
   | X -> subst
   | Add r l -> Add (substEx subst r) (substEx subst l)
   | Sub r l -> Sub (substEx subst r) (substEx subst l)
   | Mul r l -> Mul (substEx subst r) (substEx subst l)
   | Div r l -> Div (substEx subst r) (substEx subst l)
```